# a CLI music player which supports (or can be configured) to only display filenames

Tags: linux, open-source, command-line, music

My audio library tags have always been completely broken, I don't have any any desire to manage them manually and Musicbrainz Picard doesn't necessarily retrieve (or have) the specific release I've ripped (which would be unreasonable to always expect). I've always found especially the 'genre' tag utterly useless and stores such as Bandcamp include some promotion at least in the "comment" field.

Comment: mpv can be used and fzf for instance can add the fuzzy search.

Comment: If you prefer mpv/fzf you can enter as a solution. I have not used them myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/downloads.html) has the ability to show filename columns (e.g. Filename, Full Name, URI), in addition to many other fields like Artist, Track Name, Year, etc. You just need to enable preferred columns by right-clicking on any column, then select the desired ones.

You can also navigate by Folders, if you prefer that, via its "File System" browser.

It has an extensive search facility. You can see more details on Search [here](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/searching.html#searching).

You can also play FLAC, MP3, etc and has many other features.

It is open source, and runs on Linux, Windows, MacOS.

See [here](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html) for a full list of features.

To play from command line, see manual of arguments [here](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/commands/quodlibet.html)